# mysqli_fetch_assoc just returns result for one iteration

Tags: php

mysqli_fetch_assoc inside a while loop which is inside a for loop but gets response for only first iteration of the for loop.

Tried to print it on console but no response there as well.

```
for($i=0; $i<$subject_count_result['subject_count']; $i++){
    echo '<tr><td></td><td><select name="subject_id[]" id="subject_id[]" class="form-control"><option value="select" >Select</option>';
    while($sub_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stdsubject)){
        echo '<option value="'.$sub_result['id'].'">'.$sub_result['name'].'</option>';
    }
    echo  '</select></td><td>';
    echo '<select name="teacher_id[]" id="teacher_id[]" class="form-control"><option value="select" >Select</option>';
    while($teacher_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($all_branch_teacher_raw)){
        echo '<script>console.log('.$teacher_result['id'].')</script>';
        echo '<option value="'.$teacher_result['id'].'">'.$teacher_result['first_name'].' '.$teacher_result['last_name'].'</option>';                         
    }   
    echo '</select>';
    echo '</td><td></td></tr>';
}
```

I should get the same select option in each table row.

Comment: What is the value of $subject_count_result['subject_count'] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the behaviour of `mysqli_fetch_*` methods. They iterate over result set, fetch row by row and when there're no rows left each consequence call to `mysqli_fetch_` will return nothing.

In your case, you should reduce iterating over the same rows. This can be done the following way:

```
// iterate over your results once and collect them to a string
$stdSubjectOptions = '';
while($sub_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stdsubject)){
    $stdSubjectOptions .= '<option value="'.$sub_result['id'].'">'.$sub_result['name'].'</option>';
}

// iterate over your results once and collect them to a string
$teachers = '';
while($teacher_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($all_branch_teacher_raw)){
    $teachers .= '<script>console.log('.$teacher_result['id'].')</script>';
    $teachers .= '<option value="'.$teacher_result['id'].'">'.$teacher_result['first_name'].' '.$teacher_result['last_name'].'</option>';                         
} 

for($i=0; $i<$subject_count_result['subject_count']; $i++){
    echo '<tr><td></td><td><select name="subject_id[]" id="subject_id[]" class="form-control"><option value="select" >Select</option>';
    // just output previously formed string
    echo $stdSubjectOptions;    
    echo  '</select></td><td>';
    echo '<select name="teacher_id[]" id="teacher_id[]" class="form-control"><option value="select" >Select</option>';
    // just output previously formed string
    echo $teachers;
    echo '</select>';
    echo '</td><td></td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Worked like a charm.